# Why is the circuit breaker to the outside panel very warm to the touch and makes a noise when moved?

Tags: electrical, wiring

When I touched the circuit breaker in the outside panel coming off the power meter it's was almost hot to the touch and made a noise.  So I moved it again and did the same thing. My lights flicker and the microwave cuts on and off when using it.

Comment: It is loose or needs replacing, probably should just have it replaced.  This is probably the main breaker, so need an electrician to replace.  Power needs to be turned off first.  You cannot turn off power to this breaker yourself.

Comment: @crip659  Completely agree, but adding emphasis to your comment (which you might consider being an answer), this is dangerous and needs to be addressed immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Your main breaker isn't solidly connected to the panel and that's why it's getting hot. This can happen because the breaker is old and the clips or contact points of the breaker have lost their "spring" and the breaker needs to be replaced. The problem will only get worse and can lead to arcing which will result in major damage to the panel and could cause a fire. This isn't a DIY project because you can't turn off the power to that breaker. It has to be turned off by an electrician authorized to remove the meter or by the power company. You need to get this fixed pronto. Until you do, avoid using any large appliances like, ovens, stoves, electric heat or AC units, ETC.

Comment: Yeah. Pretty much.  The heat is arcing damage burning up the breaker and its lug attachments.  If you leave it to arc too long, it'll chew up the attach points and then you'll need a new panel.